How to change font size **only** for \lstinline{}?
At first sight, this may look as a duplicate of another question already closed as a duplicate of this one. But it isn't ;-)
How do I set globally the font size of all \lstinline macros, independently of the font size of lstlisting environments?
The default I have for the environments is \small, which looks very good, but I need normal size for inlines since it intermixes better with the surrounding text.
Below, as requested, a MWE showing the repetition of \lstset macros:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,numbers=left}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Displayed code listings
    Look great
In a small font
\end{lstlisting}

I would like \lstinline{inline listings} to be at normalsize as in
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}%
\lstinline{this piece of code}
but then I have to issue a new \verb|lstset| macro
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small}%
in order to get back to small size

\begin{lstlisting}
for displayed code listings
    to show appropiately.
again
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}



Even if your question is clear, could you please add a minimal example with a lstlisting environment and a \lstinline macro? It'd be easier for us to answer.

@CarLaTeX, Yes to the three sentences. I'll hold acceptance before I provide the  MWE.

@CarLaTeX MWE added

My answer added :)

I liked all the three answers very much. I'm accepting @CarLaTeX's for being the seemingly less disruptive.
Though I know what you did! Making me write half of it! xD

That‘s the trick :D Thank you for accepting my answer!

What about creating a new command as \myinline in my MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,numbers=left}
\newcommand{\myinline}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle={\ttfamily\normalsize}]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Displayed code listings
    Look great
In a small font
\end{lstlisting}

I would like \lstinline{inline listings} to be at normalsize as in
\myinline{this piece of code}
but then I have to issue a new \verb|lstset| macro
in order to get back to small size

\begin{lstlisting}
for displayed code listings
    to show appropiately.
again
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}



Looking in the code, there is no such method of distinguishing between the two. But we seem to be able to make one, because \lstinline does run \lstset internally, so we could add a patch. No idea if this has other consequences.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor,xpatch}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
}

% style for inline
\lstdefinestyle{foobar}{
  basicstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily\tiny,
}

% \ShowCommand\lstinline shows \lstinline runs \lstset{flexiblecolumns,#1}, so we mess with that
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\lstinline{flexiblecolumns,}{flexiblecolumns,style=foobar,}{}{\typeout{patch failed}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
FooBar
\end{lstlisting}

inline \lstinline|FooBar|
\end{document}



Save \lstinline with another name and redefine it to pass the original one also the option basicstyle=\ttfamily (without \small).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,numbers=left}

\NewCommandCopy{\originallstinline}{\lstinline}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\lstinline}{O{}}{%
  \originallstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1]%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Displayed code listings
    Look great
In a small font
\end{lstlisting}

Here I see that \lstinline{inline listings} is at normalsize
and there is no need to issue a new \verb|lstset| macro
in order to get back to small size

\begin{lstlisting}
for displayed code listings
    to show appropriately.
again
\end{lstlisting}

We can also pass options like in \lstinline[language=TeX]|\LaTeX|

\end{document}


